# Unable to create documents with the same object ID in different arrays due to "duplicate key error"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a new `Group` with an array of user ID's but getting the error `E11000 duplicate key error index: bullet-time.groups.$users_1 dup key`

I can create the first group fine and get the following object returned:

```
{
  "_id": "5acddf7a599e250f79cebc21",
  "users": [
    ObjectId("5ac4ab6e951bb2153ca2749e")
  ]
}
```

But upon trying to create a new group with the same user ObjectId is when I get the aforementioned error.

My group model is simple:

```
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
    users: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

And upon creating, I simply create a new group, push the user ObjectId into the users array and call save like so:

```
async create(user_id){
    try {
        const newGroup = new GroupModel()
        newGroup.users.push(user_id)
        return await newGroup.save()
    }catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

I can't see any reason why 1 user can't be in multiple groups.

As far as I can see, there are no `unique` or `dedup` flags in my models.

EDIT:

If I change my model to accept users as an array of strings as opposed to ObjectId's like so `users: [{ type : String, ref: 'User' }],` then I don't get the duplication error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped my `Groups` collections and it has seemed to resolve the issue.

I had played around with making the users array unique when attempting to make sure there were no duplicate ID's in the array. This was obviously the wrong way to do it and when it created the `Groups` collection it had obviously saved that unique attribute.

This is news to me so hopefully this helps anybody else who has a similar issue.